# Flutter: Asset Not Found inside pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

this is my project structure:

```html
your_project/
|-- android/
|-- ios/
|-- lib/
|-- assets/
    |-- test0.json // **Can access**
|   |-- file1.png
|   |-- file2.json
|   |-- ...
|   |-- jsons/
|       |-- test.json // **Can't access**
|       |-- file3.json
|       |-- file4.json
|       |-- ...
|-- pubspec.yaml
|-- ...
```

this is my pubspec.yaml:

```html
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/jsons/
```

**Reading the file:**

```html
Future<void> initSupportFiles() async {
  try {
    // Get the Application Support directory path
    Directory appSupportDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    String appSupportPath = appSupportDir.path;

    // Check if the JSON file already exists in the Application Support directory
    String jsonFilePath = '$appSupportPath/jsons/test.json';
    File jsonFile = File(jsonFilePath);

    if (await jsonFile.exists()) {
      return;
    }

    // Read the JSON file from assets directly
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/jsons/test.json');
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    await jsonFile.writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List());

    print('JSON file copied to Application Support directory.');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error copying JSON file: $e');
  }
}
```

**My problem:** I can't access ANY files inside subfolders inside Assets (only files inside the root of Assets are accessible)

I tried doing `flutter pub get`, but it didn't work. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `initSupportFiles` function, the `getApplicationSupportDirectory` function from the `path_provider` package returns a directory path specific to the platform  If you are testing the app on an emulator or simulator, these directories might not be accessible directly.you can use `rootBundle` to load and access them directly without relying on platform specific directories.

you can update you `initSupportFiles` function with..

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<void> initSupportFiles() async {
  try {
    // Check if the JSON file already exists in the Application Support directory
    String jsonFilePath = 'assets/jsons/test.json';
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(jsonFilePath);
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    List<int> bytes = buffer.asUint8List();

    // Write the JSON file to a specific location (e.g., Application Support directory)
    // For testing purposes, you can use a different path like the Documents directory
    Directory appSupportDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    String appSupportPath = appSupportDir.path;
    String jsonFilePathInSupport = '$appSupportPath/test.json';

    File jsonFile = File(jsonFilePathInSupport);
    if (await jsonFile.exists()) {
      return;
    }
    await jsonFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    print('JSON file copied to Application Support directory.');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error copying JSON file: $e');
  }
}
```

Comment: getApplicationSupportDirectory is still being used in your example, and also the path is wrong at jsonFilePathInSupport. Is that a mistake or am I missing something?

Comment: @PreemPalver2 In Flutter, when specifying assets in the pubspec.yaml file, you don't need to include subfolders explicitly. By including the parent folder, all the files within it and its subfolders are automatically considered as assets.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing positional spaces or adding, if its incorrect, or maybe restarting your ide? if the emulator is running, try restarting that as well.

Comment: my first answer on this website was exactly same HAHAHAHA.... look for the fields you know best about and only answer the questions on which you have confidence. Good luck for your journey

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @nischalsharma were you answered in the same manner like you answered me? hehehe

Comment: @nischalsharma keeping it fresh i see

Comment: @maak47 i meant suggesting restarting/re-installing the software everytime..... haha